# Can't get rid of "Don't Miss Your Dream Job"

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

On careers there is a box about not missing your dream job.  On it, it states:

> Don't miss your dream job. Matches increase significantly for developers who fill out their:
>
> Personal statement
>
> Job matching preferences

I've got both filled out and this box never seems to go away.  Can we please hide this box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's planned, it will go away if you meet the requirements.

Comment: Planned for when? Can we get a date? What is the plan? This answer doesn't really seem to address the question so much as wave it off, if I'm honest.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Before the feature gets out of beta is probably a safe assumption.

Comment: It means "this is a planned fix". Confusingly worded, I think.